# RESTful api for database management

Tags: database, rest, crud, api-design, database-management

I have a restful api pet project and I thought I could make it better for others to use.

I'm not entirely sure about the applicability of such api but the question is whether it is supposed to manage user's (developer's) database by giving him various templates of models and data types, if there is such a thing then I suspect there are already plenty of those, so I'm not sure anybody would even use it in their work even if it was to be advertised.

I'm also not entirely sure if it's even legal for an api to be able to do this, like if the users would have to subscribe for this service then I could be able to steal their data? Or is it something that should simply be a matter of trust?

I tried searching information about apis managing user's databases that they give as input and then perform various CRUD operations according to the templates and functions given by my api, I couldn't find a lot so I assumed it's something that can be done but I am not sure if it even falls under the definition of an http api.

Comment: Giving an external server that level of access to a company's database seems like a security risk, and might violate security standards like SOC2 and TxRAMP.  Typically the only time an external service is given access to a company's data is when that company is hosting it as a service, like Salesforce for salespeople, and the company doing that must have its own (SOC2, TxRAMP, etc.) security certifications.

Comment: @DaveS hosting as a service, you mean like web hosting? Except that in my case I don't provide a web server or any other storage for the user. Thanks for the answer

Comment: No, "Software as a Service" like Microsoft 365, Salesforce, Zendesk, etc. where they have access to the data because they are providing both servers and the applications that process the data.